# Using the same asp.net user control in multiple update panels

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an update panel on two different pages. I want to use the same user control on both pages and assign it to the update panel with asyncpostbacktrigger. It runs fine in the dev environment but then gets a java script error when we put it into the live site.

I understand you cant use the same user control in multiple update panels, but is there anyway around this?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Here is the code for my first page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Licensing.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VendorLicenses.aspx.cs" Inherits="Licensing.Web.ManageLicenses.VendorLicenses" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ManageLicenses/OwnerLicenseEdit.ascx" TagName="LicenseEdit" TagPrefix="licensing" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EditLicense(LicenseID) {
            // set title
            if (LicenseID == "")
            {
                $get('<%= LicensePanelHeaderText.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Add License";
                $get('<%= LicenseEditDelete.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                $get('<%= LicensePanelHeaderText.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Edit License";
                $get('<%= LicenseEditDelete.ClientID %>').style.display = "";
            }

            <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(LicenseEdit, "[LicenseID]").Replace("'[LicenseID]'", "LicenseID") %>
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager" />

    <font style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;">Vendor Licenses</font>
    <br /><br />

<!-- License Popup -->
&nbsp<a href='javascript:EditLicense("");'>Add License</a>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="AddLicense" style="display:none;" />

<asp:Panel ID="LicensePanel" runat="server" style="display:none; width:100%;" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:Panel ID="LicensePanelHeader" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LicensePanelHeaderText" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large; text-decoration:underline;"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="LicenseUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LicenseEdit" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LicenseEditSave" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LicenseEditDelete" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <licensing:LicenseEdit runat="server" ID="LicenseEdit" OnLicenseLoaded="LicenseEdit_OnLicenseLoaded" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the code for my second page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Licensing.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OwnerLicenses.aspx.cs" Inherits="Licensing.Web.ManageLicenses.OwnerLicenses" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ManageLicenses/OwnerLicenseEdit.ascx" TagName="LicenseEdit" TagPrefix="licensing" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EditLicense(LicenseID) {
            // set title
            if (LicenseID == "")
            {
                $get('<%= LicensePanelHeaderText.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Add License";
                $get('<%= LicenseEditDelete.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                $get('<%= LicensePanelHeaderText.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Edit License";
                $get('<%= LicenseEditDelete.ClientID %>').style.display = "";
            }

            <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(LicenseEdit, "[LicenseID]").Replace("'[LicenseID]'", "LicenseID") %>
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager" />

    <font style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;">Prasco Licenses</font>
    <br /><br />

<!-- License Popup -->
&nbsp<a href='javascript:EditLicense("");'>Add License</a>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="AddLicense" style="display:none;" />

<asp:Panel ID="LicensePanel" runat="server" style="display:none; width:100%;" CssClass="modalPopup">
    <asp:Panel ID="LicensePanelHeader" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LicensePanelHeaderText" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large; text-decoration:underline;"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="LicenseUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LicenseEdit" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LicenseEditSave" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LicenseEditDelete" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <licensing:LicenseEdit runat="server" ID="LicenseEdit" OnLicenseLoaded="LicenseEdit_OnLicenseLoaded" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any code samples? Help us to help you.

Comment: I included the code for my update panels above. As you can see, its using the same control for the update panels on two different pages. The error that I get when running the page is a java script error. Is there a way to use the same user control on two different update panels?

Comment: Can you add the errormessage to your question please?